# Re-using standard message in custom page (Pascal code)

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to change or get text from Inno Setup main panel?

I would like to use only underlined part of the text in my custom Wizard page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`SetupMessage` support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_setupmessage):

```
Label.Caption := SetupMessage(msgLicenseLabel);
```

See the `Default.isl` for names of the standard messages.